# Microcontroller on/off circuit in battery power device

Tags: microcontroller, power, mosfet, logic-gates, reset

I am using the below circuit to turn ON and OFF my load microcontroller circuit in my battery powered device. The max current draw I'm expecting is around 800mA. 
My logic is like this.

For power up - When I long press switch 3,my NOR gate gives a low output, driving my P-channel drain output high,powering up my microcontroller. From my code I drive the input A of NOR gate high so that the NOR gate output remains latched at low and my MOSFET drain output remains high despite me lifting my finger from the switch. 
I follow something similar for power down.

My questions are  -

1. Is there a better way to design this ? Got me wondering how mobile phones' power on/off circuits are designed.
2. I also did face some problems while I tested this circuit. When my power is down, i.e. when I want MOSFET to be off, I still see around 0.8V at the drain. This isn't causing any problems as such since my MCU doesn't power up, but its got me worrying that this will drain my battery.I was expecting a 0 at the drain.[image]

Comment: Have a look at LTC2954. This is used in a lot of mobile devices

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why my P-mosfet isn't turning off fully?

Comment: Not really. What is your source - gate voltage when you have it turned off?

Comment: It is about 23mV. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Sounds quite good to me, but I'm no expert in MOS technology. You could try to remove R63 (open) for a test and add a pullup from the gate to 5V.  Does it get better?

Comment: Mobile phone power management and on/off is controlled by a PMIC. and it is quite a lucrative business

Comment: Removing R63 didn't improve things. 
After further tests this is what I've figured - The 0.8V on the MOSFET appeared even without conncting the load. Its something that is showing up because of voltage appearing on the secondary of my fixed output LDO,i.e. 3.3V end (5V to 3.3V one). I'm still trying to understand why that's happening. 
Even my 5V seems to become 3.6V instead of 3.3V due to some feedback! My 5V comes from a PMIC. Problem with putting that in sleep mode is I need to make a certain pin on that IC low from my uC. Ok for PWR down but for PWR up with uC unpowered, how do I do this?